# handle dynamic url from flask

Tags: python, angularjs, google-app-engine, flask

UPDATE : Fixed this !!

used `/.*` pointing to `dist/index.html`

---

I am trying to create a web application which has url of the form

`www.example.com/qa3h`

( Please change the title if there is better terminology for such apps)

I am using

- Google App Engine ( Python )
- Flask
- AngularJs

in my `app.yaml` I configured, all `/api` to go to the `main.app` , and `/` to `dist/index.html`

I configured angular to use html5mode , so no # symbol

but I am not sure how to handle `example.com/qa3h`

What I did ...

I could navigate from the application . For ex. in `example.com/` if I do `$locationProvider.url('/qa3h')` , I am navigating to the required url. But if I directly paste the url in the browser it gives `cannot GET /qa3h`

My configuration files .
angular config

```
 .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/:appId', {
        templateUrl: '/views/app.html',
        controller: 'appCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
  });
```

app.yaml

```
- url: /api/.*
  script: main.app

- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this !!

used /.* pointing to dist/index.html